# Line separator using com.lowagie.text.pdf

Tags: itext, pdf-generation, horizontal-line

I'm trying to insert a line separator - horizontal line. Currently I am using iText 2.1.7 or older (`com.lowagie.text.pdf`) to generate my PDF file.

There is no option available for line separator in `document.add()` as like in a more recent version of iText.

We have a `LineSeparator` object only in `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.draw.DottedLineSeparator` (iText 5 or newer).

Since most of my applications are using iText 2.1.7 or older, I don't want to switch them to iText 5 or newer.

Is there any option in `com.lowagie.text.pdf` for line separator?

Comment: Well, you have already given the answer yourself: you found a feature that is not available in an ancient version of iText, and is only available in a more recent version of iText.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed my entire application to use latest version of iText. It works Great!!